# When I edit an answer and hit save, Chrome Prompts me: "You have started editing this post, Abandon This Edit?"

Tags: bug

Clicking OK refreshes the page and my answer is gone/invisible.

Refreshing the page leads to a proper looking page that includes my edits.

Detected on ProWebmasters

[image]

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, valid duplicate. I'd edit that answer to include my screenshot, and make the title more descriptive (like mine). I notice it has no answer either. In fact, this issue is raised in a couple of other places, none of which seem to have answers. Clearly this is an issue, closing this will bury it.